# Slide Show com Divs

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Preciso fazer tipo uma slide show só que com notícias, mais especificamente um slide show de divs. E ainda não encontrei uma forma de fazer isso! Alguém poderia me ajudar? Abraço

Comment: Podes explicar melhoro que queres fazer e como está o teu HTML? Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17612/129

Comment: tenho 2 divs que ocupando 100% de largura e uma seta de "próximo" e ao  clicar nessa seta, as duas divs somem e vem mais 2 divs, entende?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link, creio que pode te ajudar: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?90HyndWc Apenas complementando, você pode encontrar diversos estilos no link abaixo: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-news-ticker/ Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Há um jeito simples utilizando a biblioteca do **Bootstrap**, segue um exemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Imagem 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Notícia 01
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Imagem 2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Notícia 02
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Imagem 3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Notícia 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Fonte: [Bootstrap Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)